# Can we jump to another location from a location in nginx?

Tags: nginx, configuration

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
location /location1/{
    if ($arg_api_key = a_valid_api_key) {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
    # else jump to location2
}
location /location2/{
    # a lot of validation code here
}
```

How do we do it in nginx? Or is there a better way handling it?

Comment: What do you mean by “jump” — rewrite the URL to `/location2/...`, or keep the URL as `/location1/...` and just reuse settings for `/location2/`?

Comment: the second one: keep the URL as /location1/... and just reuse settings for /location2/

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

First, remember that [if is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) and avoid putting anything except `rewrite` or `return` inside `if`; a workaround suggested there is to use `error_page` and `return` to change location used to process the request.

As [already answered here](https://serverfault.com/a/373661/63156), the way to reuse location settings in nginx is to move them to a separate file and `include` that file in your `location` blocks.

Combining these solutions results in:

#### /etc/nginx/validation_code.conf

```
# a lot of validation code here
```

#### main config

```
location /location1/ {
    error_page 418 = @proxy;
    recursive_error_pages on;
    if ($arg_api_key = a_valid_api_key) {
        return 418;
    }
    include /etc/nginx/validation_code.conf;
}

location /location2/ {
    include /etc/nginx/validation_code.conf;
}

location @proxy {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

You may also think about using a named location for your validation code instead of creating a separate file; however, you will need some tricks to switch to that named location — e.g., another `error_page`/`return` pair, or something like

```
    try_files /nonexistent @validation
```

Comment: error_page 418 = @proxy; -> It works for me. However, all the parameters are lost. Is there a way to do it with all the parameters?